# Can't login to Magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, backend, login, admin-panel

For test and development, I duplicated our Magento shop to a sub-domain.

> mysql -u root -p -e "USE bitnami_magento; UPDATE core_config_data SET
>   value ='http://subdomain.site.com/' WHERE core_config_data.path =
>   'web/unsecure/base_url'; UPDATE core_config_data SET value
>   ='https://subdomain.site.com/' WHERE core_config_data.path = 'web/secure/base_url';

Everything works, but not the admin Login. On the login page we get it. After entering my user name and password we don't log in. Login error message ("invalid password", etc.) ISN`T being displayed.

We are using 1.9.0.1

Removing cache files ...

```
sudo rm -r /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/cache/*
sudo rm -r /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/session/*
```

.. and restarting Apache ..

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

.. Does not help.

Please any advice - what could be the reason?

Comment: UPD: It works on the browser FireFox. Problems logging in Admin Panel (Backend) with Opera and Chrome. Also, there is no problem with login in other computers with different browsers. Perhaps the problem is "session cookie". Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Its related to cookies.

1. First remove the cookies related to site in your current browser and check login.
2. After login, please increase the cookies timeout to 1 day.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But please specify in detail how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, in Developer Tools (right-click on any page element and select Inspect Element), go to the Resources -> Cookies tab. Delete the extra cookie for your original domain. Or set your base url domain to something else, or change the port.

Comment: Also, Ctrl + Shift + Delete (for non-apple computers)

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable "Ban attacking ips from accessing site" in Firewall section or try to login with different IP address.